# How do I get the content of an input text?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm simply trying to use whatever is typed into the `<input type="text">` as a variable for my script.

I've tried .select() .value() .val() and it keeps returning undefined or null. I'm trying to do it async so the page doesnt have to refresh but it doesn't want to work as I intend.

```
$(function() {
    $('#changeDistance').click(function(e) { e.preventDefault();
        console.log('Triggered');
        setDistance = $('#setDistance').select();
        console.log($('#setDistance').select());
        for (var i = 0; i < markersArray.length; i++) {
            markersArray[i].setMap(null);
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < database.length; i++) {
            createMarker(database[i].latitude, database[i].longitude, database[i].markerTitle, initialLocation);
        }

    });
});
```

is where I'm trying to use it

Comment: can you show some html to go along with this?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming your input is indeed as follows: `<input type="text" id="setDistance" />` then the correct function to get its value in jQuery is `.val()`.

However, if you write `$("#setDistance").val()` then I will lynch you. Use `document.getElementById('setDistance').value` instead.

Comment: @Kolink: Could you expound upon why `document.getElementById(id).value` is preferred over `$(selector).val()`, as you've implied?

Comment: I'm getting this error in console.log` TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null
[Break On This Error]  

setDistance = document.getElementById('setDistance').value;`

Comment: I could, but [this webpage](http://vanilla-js.com/) does it SO much better than I ever could.

Comment: @XCritics That means you don't have an element with that ID. This would also explain why your attempts to get the values result in `undefined`. See the HTML I assume you to be using in my first sentence.

Comment: I fixed it, I think it's cause my id had the same name as my global variable

Comment: @Kolink: That is hilarious! And indeed true! I love it. Very tongue-in-cheek.

Comment: @Kolink I had the id name same as my global variables name, changing the id name made it work, why is that

Comment: In some browsers, elements with IDs are automatically registered as global variables, causing interference. It's one of the reasons not to use global variables.

Comment: @Kolink—if the input is in a form (which it should be) and its name is unique (which it many not be but probably is) then there is no need for any function calls, the OP can use direct property access: `document.forms.formNameOrID.inputName.value`.

Comment: @RobG Indeed, however that's a lot of "ifs" and I've never really liked that way of doing things. I don't know why, it just seems odd to me for some reason.

Comment: @Kolink—in such browsers (let's be open, you're talking about IE and sycophants) if a global variable and element ID are the same, provided the global is declared then it trumps the element reference.

Comment: Yes, it's true. I've fallen prey to this "feature" myself :p But I solved it by using a closure and a local variable. And then I renamed the variable for good measure (even though it already worked fine as a local var)

Comment: @Kolink—yes, it's good ol' DOM 0. Accommodating it leads to good (robust) design and code. Well, it should do that. Some will still mess it up. :-(

Answer (score 2):

First you need to specify and `Id` to your input tag

Use this

```
$('#inputID').val()`
```

With ID you need to use `#` and if you specify a class then you need to use period `.`
If you give class (class is assigned to many attribute) then you will get array. So you need to access each element by index

```
$('.classname').each(function() {  
   $(this).val();  
});
```

Comment: Consider yourself lynched. (See my answer for this comment's reason)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$("input[id$='setDistance']").val();
```

Comment: @Kolink—haven't you heard that jQuery makes your code so much more readable? And if you use it in one place, you should use it everywhere for everything to make code consistent and maintenance easier? Where have you been???

Comment: @RobG Buried six fathoms deep under an ocean of vanilla ice-cream. Yummy.

Comment: Just so you know, I'm in Review|Low Quality Posts right now. "This answer was automatically flagged as low-quality because of its length and content." LOL!

Answer (score 0):

you can use by Textbox id

```
$("#TextboxId").val();
```

or

```
$("input[type='text']").val();
```

or

```
$(".text-classname").val();
```

Comment: You too have been lynched.